# Update file configuration but preserve previous value via Ansible

Tags: ansible

Is possible to update file configuration via `lineinfile` or different module but preserve previous value?

For example:

```
SOME_ARGS=" -AA:1AA -BB:2BB -CC:3CC"
```

Add at the end of the line or begining `-DD:4DD` so result will be:

```
SOME_ARGS=" -AA:1AA -BB:2BB -CC:3CC -DD:4DD"
```

or

```
SOME_ARGS="-DD:4DD -AA:1AA -BB:2BB -CC:3CC"
```

This won't work as it will replace text with line value:

```
- lineinfile:
    path: "/some/file.txt"
    regexp: "^SOME_ARGS=.*-DD:4DD"
    line: "-DD:4DD"
    insertafter: "^SOME_ARGS=\""
    state: present
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It's something difficult with Ansible, I recommend you that these value changes were stored on a VCS, after that you can go back to any previous value.

Using lineinfile, a simple solution can be to apply the module twice, one pass to comment previous value, putting a # at the start for example, and the second one that will insert a new line after this commented one with the new value.

Take care that you regexp need to take care of other file values, this module in Ansible is a bit dificult to get working correctly with some configuration files.